# What are some meagre subsets of this topological space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I was wondering if you have the topological space $ X = ([0, 1] \times [0, 1], \tau_{dict})$ where $\tau_{dict}$ is the dictionary topology, what would be a meagre subset of this space?

My first guess was to consider $B = \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] \times \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$. To show this set meagre, I first considered a singleton $A = \left\{q \times q' \right\}$ for $q, q' \in \mathbb{Q}$. I want to prove it is closed in $X$, and that its interior is empty, so that it is a nowhere dense subset. Then I could write $B$ as a countable union of sets of this type.

But I wasn't sure already how to prove that a singleton of the kind $\left\{q \times q' \right\}$ is closed in $X$. I took any point $z = (x,y)$ in the closure. Then for any neighborhood $V_z$ of $z$ I know that $V_z \cap \left\{q \times q' \right\} \neq \emptyset. $ I don't know how to proceed, and maybe this approach is even wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For an order topology, sets of the form $\{ x : x < p\}$ or $\{ x : x > p\}$ are open.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Can you explain what that means in more detail?

Comment: It means that singletons are closed, since the complement of $\{p\}$ is $\{ x : x < p\} \cup \{ x : x > p\}$.